# SQL select MAX to find single record of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have many records that represent the same information, but with different keys to other tables.  I need to group these records by their common attributes (Att1, Att2, Att3), then select a single RecordID of all the common records to be the masterID for those common records.  That masterID needs to be added to each record that it represents, only if the masterID is null.  I cannot change the data structure and all table values are GUID.  I have tried MAX, but I dont get the grouping.

```
TableA (Current State)

RecordID          Att1         Att2     Att3     MasterID
1                 A            B        C        
2                 A            B        C
3                 A            B        C
4                 D            E        F
5                 D            E        F
6                 D            E        F
7                 G            H        I         7
8                 G            H        I         7
9                 G            H        I         7
```

UPDATE:  Added expected result.

```
TableA (Expected Result)

RecordID          Att1         Att2     Att3     MasterID
1                 A            B        C        1
2                 A            B        C        1
3                 A            B        C        1
4                 D            E        F        4
5                 D            E        F        4
6                 D            E        F        4
7                 G            H        I        7
8                 G            H        I        7
9                 G            H        I        7
```

Comment: Is that your current data or your expected result? In case it is the former, can you provide an example of your expected result?

Comment: Are you trying to make a query to update the MasterID column or the expected result is the result of the select statement?

Comment: @MostyMostacho  sorry about that.  i have added the expected results.

Comment: @ImGreg  i am trying to make a query to identify an ID to use as a MasterID, then use that MAsterID to update the MAsterID column.

Comment: I've updated my answer to accommodate the update @sreeli.

Answer (score 3):

Yuck, I dislike this setup.  You're violating good normalization practices, and there's some inherent assumptions that require 'outside' knowledge.  However, you've said you can't change it so...

I believe the following should work (vendor neutral):

```
UPDATE TableA as a SET masterId = (SELECT MIN(b.recordId) 
                                   FROM TableA as b
                                   WHERE b.att1 = a.att1
                                   AND b.att2 = a.att2
                                   AND b.att3 = a.att3)
WHERE masterId IS NULL
```

---

EDIT:

Upon the revelation that GUIDs can be ordered, but cannot be passed for `MIN()` or `MAX()` (What?) -

You have (at least) three options:

1. Cast the guid to a passable type (ie - `SELECT MIN(CAST(b.recordId as CHAR(36)))`).  However, this is likely to be poor performing, simply because it's going to cast every row (see, this is why it's preferrable for internal ids to be simple integers).
2. Attempt this vendor-neutral statement:

   ```
   UPDATE TableA as a SET masterId = (SELECT b.recordId
                                      FROM TableA as b
                                      LEFT JOIN TableA as c
                                      ON c.att1 = b.att1
                                      AND c.att2 = b.att2
                                      AND c.att3 = b.att3
                                      AND c.recordId < b.recordId
                                      WHERE b.att1 = a.att1
                                      AND b.att2 = a.att2
                                      AND b.att3 = a.att3
                                      AND b.recordId <= a.recordId
                                      AND c.recordId IS NULL)
   WHERE masterId IS NULL
   ```
3. There's also this more idiomatic version for SQL Server:

   ```
   UPDATE Updating
   SET Updating.masterId = Origin.recordId
   FROM TableA Updating
   JOIN (TableA Origin
         LEFT JOIN TableA Exclusion
                ON Exclusion.att1 = Origin.att1
                   AND Exclusion.att2 = Origin.att2
                   AND Exclusion.att3 = Origin.att3
                   AND Exclusion.recordId < Origin.recordId) 
     ON Exclusion.recordId IS NULL
        AND Origin.att1 = Updating.att1
        AND Origin.att2 = Updating.att2
        AND Origin.att3 = Updating.att3
   WHERE Updating.masterId IS NULL
   ```

   <kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9dc71/12/1)</kbd>

Comment: @X-Zero   Yuck is right. i inherited this and in way over my head.   recordid is a guid so min doesnt work.

Comment: @X-Zero  the cast worked great.  one note thought, when casting quids to char in sql server, you need to specificy a length of at at least 36.  SELECT MIN(CAST(b.recordId as CHAR(36))) THANKS FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE m
SET
    MasterID = s.RecordID
FROM TableA AS m
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Att1, Att2, Att3, MIN(RecordID) AS RecordID          
    FROM TableA 
    GROUP BY Att1, Att2, Att3
) AS s
    ON m.Att1 = s.Att1 AND m.Att2 = s.Att2 AND m.Att3 = s.Att3
WHERE
    MasterID  IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select only then you can use the following query -

```
select recordid ,
       Att1,
       Att2,
       Att3,
       COALESCE( MasterID , (select min(a2.recordid) from tableA a2
                            where a2.Att1 = a1.Att1
                            and a2.Att2= a1.Att2
                            and a1.Att3 = a2.Att3))
from TableA a1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross apply to make a selection.  The cross apply basically selects the lowest RecordID that has matching Att1, Att2, and Att3 and joins the RecordID as a column named MasteRID.

```
WITH temp as (SELECT RecordID, Att1, Att2, Att3, c.MasterID FROM dbo.TableA b
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 RecordID as MasterID 
    FROM dbo.TableA a 
    WHERE a.Att1=b.Att1 
    AND a.Att2=b.Att2 AND a.Att3=b.Att3 
    ORDER BY RecordID) c)

UPDATE TableA 
SET MasterID=t.MasterID
FROM temp t
WHERE RecordID=t.RecordID
```

The update will update each RecordID entry's MasterID column with the appropriate RecordID.

Comment: thanks for the update. SQL doesnt like the FROM temp t, it is ecpecting SET.